# Create new column B indicating which quintile each row, Col A is in

Tags: calculated-columns, quantile

I hope to compute which quintile each record in my data frame is in, as it relates to various columns. For example, using the mtcars dataset, I would need a column like MPG_QUINTILE. I just typed that column in and guestimated which quintile the mpg would be in. But how do I automate this?  I need to do it for several columns.  i.e HP_QUINTILE, etc.

```
mpg   MPG_QUINTILE
21    1   
25    1  
27    2  
33    3  
42    5
```

Anyway I hope to find a solution that doesn't require a custom built function.  Also, what if you want quintiles that are equally sized (same number of records per bin) vs. quintiles that are strictly based on percentiles?